# Identity involving generalisation of triangular numbers.

Tags: combinatorics

Define: $T_k^n$ for $k$ and $n \geq 0$ as follows.

$$T_0^n = 1$$

$$T_k^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n} T_{k-1}^i$$

E.g $T_1^n = \sum_{i=0}^n T_0^i = n+1$ and $T_2^n=\sum_{i=0}^nT_1^i= \sum_{i=0}^n i+1 = \binom{n+2}{2}.$

Is it true that

$$T_{k}^n = \binom{n+k}{k} ~ ? $$

Comment: Does $T$ it satisfy the recursion that the binomial coefficients do? Incidentally, you could change the base case to $T_0^n = 1$.

Comment: I'm not sure. I will check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be:
\begin{align*}
  T_{k}^n = \binom{n+k}{k}
\end{align*}

which can be proved by using convolution of generating functions. Let

\begin{align*}
  G_0(x) &= \sum_{i\ge 0} T_0^i \, x^i \\
  &= \frac{1}{1-x}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  G_1(x) &= \sum_{n\ge 0} \left(\sum_{i=0}^n T_0^i \right)x^n \\
  &= \frac{1}{1-x}G_0(x) \\  
  &= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \\
  &\hspace{14mm}\vdots\\
  &\hspace{14mm}\vdots\\
  G_k(x) &= \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} = \sum_{n\ge 0} \binom{n+k}{k} x^n
\end{align*}

Hence, we deduce that

\begin{align*}
  T_{k}^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n} T_{k-1}^i = \binom{n+k}{k}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks gar. This looks good.

Comment: You are welcome.